# List-manipulation Interpolation

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

For example, I have the following list:

```
AA={{0, 20000.}, {26.6, 19950.}, {53.2, 19950.}, {79.8, 
  19950.}, {97.1198, 18644.1}, {102.681, 16452.3}}
```

Another calculation results in an arbitrary value intended for the first part of the list, let's say 21.3. By interpolating linearly, this results in a value of 19960 for the second part of the list.

How can I import this in Mathematica?

Comment: what would an improvement look like? What value would you expect?

Comment: I would expect an value of 19960 (In case of 21.3 in the first part of the list), but I don't know how to program this in Mathematica..

Answer (score 2):

If you use an `InteprolationOrder->1` things work as you expect:

```
if = Interpolation[AA, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
if[21.3]
(*19960.*)
```